# Display GET SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, get

I have this query

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT (`title`) AS title, author, copyright, section, dds FROM bookhistory GROUP BY acc_number, title, author, copyright, section, dds";
```

It works perfectly fine if I want to display all the data from the table. But one of the data, I appended this:

```
echo "<td>".$row['section']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['dds']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='../php/borrowersname.php?acc_number=".$row['acc_number']."'>".$row['title']."</a></td>"; //thi one
echo "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['copyright']."</td>";
```

On my borrowersname.php, the result does not really get the account number:

```
borrowersname.php?acc_number=
```

It's blank. Why is that? Thanks in advance for some additional learning.

Comment: `acc_number` is not selected in the query

Comment: Okay, so do i have to make my query like this? SELECT DISTINCT (`title`, `acc_number`) AS title, ....

Comment: Really, you shouldn't have `DISTINCT (title) AS title`, simply doing 'SELECT DISTINCT' will get you what you want. As in, `SELECT DISTINCT title, author, acc_number,...`

Comment: data not requested, wont be retrieved - funny that ;-)

Comment: It doesn't work if I use SELECT DISTINCT (`title`, `acc_number`) with AS title, author, copyright, section, dds FROM bookhistory GROUP BY acc_number, title, author, copyright, section, dds"; :(

Comment: Well that's because you can't do that. Just get rid of the `(title) AS title` and add `, acc_number` and things will work better. But this is really, really beginner level SQL, you need to read up on the basics a bit more. Also, there's no reason to ever do both a DISTINCT and a GROUP BY; they're duplicating efforts. Get rid of the DISTINCT altogether. `SELECT title, author, copyright, section, dds, acc_number FROM...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL query, you're not selecting the `acc_number` column:

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT (`title`) AS title, author, copyright, section, dds ...
```

Because of this, `$row['acc_number']` will not exist (unless you somehow populate it otherwise, but this is doubtful).

Update your query to the following (assuming `acc_number` is a valid column) and it should work:

```
$q = "SELECT title, acc_number, author, copyright, section, dds FROM bookhistory GROUP BY acc_number, title, author, copyright, section, dds";
```

Note: I removed the `DISTINCT` since you're grouping the results anyways.